# Django - trigger auto_now field change

Tags: django, django-models

I am wondering how to resave the object just to update the `auto_now` Field.

famously, this code came to my mind

```
obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=someid)
obj.save()
```

but what if i have many objects to update? or better put, what is the best way to update a object's `auto_now` field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using `save()` on each object to update the `auto_now` field.

As Daniel said, `update()` won't, in fact, update the auto_now field, because it does a direct SQL update, whereas the `auto_now` field is set in Python code.

So i did:

```
obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=someid)
obj.save()
```

and for multiple objects:

```
objs = MyModel.objects.all()
for obj in objs:
   obj.save()
```

Comment: n+1 queries are bad!

Answer (score 1):

What about using [`update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) and setting `id` value to itself to trigger `auto_now` field change:

```
from django.db.models import F

MyModel.objects.filter(something=something).update(id=F('id'))
```

Comment: never used ``F`` till now, the time came finally. thanks man :)

Comment: @doniyor thanks again for another interesting question from your collection :)

Comment: always my pleasure! ;)

Comment: This won't actually work to update the auto_now field, because `update` does a direct SQL update, whereas the auto_now is set in Python code.

Comment: @doniyor could you confirm it is not working (see Daniel's comment)? Thanks.

Comment: oh, i didnot use your solution yet. so the solution is only ``save()``?

Comment: @doniyor I'm afraid yes. Or, you can also set the date manually using `update()`. First, just try out the solution provided in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Alex, yeah i ended up using save(); sorry for not informing you. But i learnt F anyway :) thanks bro

Comment: @doniyor okay, then better unaccept the answer, add your own answer and accept it. It would help others to see what is the best solution here for now. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you very much for the point, overlooked it.

Comment: If you add note that user should manually set `auto_now` field value then this would be good answer for bigger querysets. Now the answer is just incorrect. To make it great answer you could also add note that `save()` could be used if there is just single model instance. :)